# Auto-fill date when previous cell is edited in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, autofill

I am trying to set up a google spreadsheet that would auto-fill the cell to the right when the cell in the previous column was edit at all. For example: anytime any info was changed in column C, I want the cell to the right in column D to auto-fill with the date. The same would be true for Column F, and the corresponding cell to the right in column G, and so forth and so on. Any help or script would be greatly appreciated!! I am new to Google script.

Comment: You can add what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically updating google spreadsheet with modified dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947757/automatically-updating-google-spreadsheet-with-modified-dates)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an On Edit trigger that calls a function called something like "RecordTime". That function will get the edited cell and add the current date to that cell.

My apologies if this is really bad code but you get the idea of what it's supposed to do.

```
 function myFunction(e) {

  var cell = e.range;  
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var column = cell.getColumn();

  var sheet = cell.getSheet();
  var cellBeside = sheet.getRange(row, column + 1);

  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.toString();

  cellBeside.setValue(timeStamp);  
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13sflBkW7xnwQmbKqdB0Y9VlmemMzptqrqmA7lesxwWg/edit?usp=sharing). You probably want to restrict it to "odd" or "Even" columns so that you don't start overwriting actual data with timestamps but you get the idea.

Comment: Could you provide the script for this?

Comment: Done. If this helps you, please upvote. If not, let me know.