# Timestamp function keeps automatically updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been searching, scouring the internet for a formula or code that will give me a timestamp that will stay. What I want to be able to do is have a timestamp updated only once a change to a row of cells is made.  I have tried Now(), Today(), Timestamp, and an array, and all continue to update the date every time I open the spreadsheet.

A [link to the document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10r8bWzP77RUyWhkUlBdTy623isyY406azNLTEmW8-X8/copy#gid=0) so you can see what I am talking about.

On the Master Sheet in Column R, I want the date (and time if possible) to appear there when any changes are made to row L4-Q4 and down the page.  I also want this repeated for each learning goal (Column AD, AP, etc.).  Basically, I want to know when the last time that student was assessed on a particular outcome.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947757/automatically-updating-google-spreadsheet-with-modified-dates

Comment: There are [many examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-spreadsheet]+onedit+timestamp) of `onEdit()` functions that will apply a timestamp automatically. On Web Applications as well, you'll find similar posts like [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57454).

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting those formula's via a script, they're going to function as they would if you had just typed them into the sheet - which is to say they're going to update. If you want to insert the current date/time and keep it static, just do something like:

```
var date = new Date();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").setValue(date);
```

That being said - your question isn't very appropriate for Stack Overflow which is meant for questions about existing code that you need help with. The [Google+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769) is better for broad questions like these.